# Is there a way to listen for operations / change events at the container level rather than the individual DDS level in the Fluid Framework?

Tags: fluid-framework

Scenario:
I have a service running that is keeping a global search or query index up to date for all containers in my “system”.  This service is notified any time a container is opened by a client and opens its own reference to that container to listen for changes to content in that container so it can update the “global container index” storage.  The container is potentially large and partitioned into may individual DDS entities, and I would like to avoid loading every DDS in the container in order to listen for changes in each of those DDS’s.

Ideally I would be able to listen for any “operations / changes” at the container level and dynamically load the impacted DDS to be able to transcribe the information that was updated into this external index storage.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two questions here: 1. How do I listen to container-level operations? 2. How do I load just one DDS?

### How do I listen to operations?

This is certainly possible, but is not included as a capability in the reference implementation of the service. There are multiple ways of architect-ing a solution to this.

1. Use the EventEmitter on the Container object itself. The sequencedDocumentMessage will have a `type` property. When `type === "op"`, the message contents will include metadata about a change to data. You can use the below to get a feel for this.

```js
    const container = await getTinyliciousContainer(documentId, DiceRollerContainerRuntimeFactory, createNew);

    if (sequenceDocumentMessage.type === "op") {
        console.log(sequenceDocumentMessage.contents)
    }
```

If you're looking for all of the message types and message interfaces, the [enum and the generic interface for ISequenceDocumentMessage are both here](https://github.com/Microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/main/server/routerlicious/packages/protocol-definitions/src/protocol.ts).

2. Listen directly to the Total Order Broadcast with a bespoke lambda
   If you're running the reference implementation of Fluid, you can just add a new lambda that is directly listening to Kafka (default Total Order Broadcast) and doing this job. The lambdas that are already running are located here: `server/routerlicious/packages/lambdas`. `Deli` is actually doing a fairly similar job already by listening into and labeling operations from Kafka by their Container.
3. Use the Foreman "lambda" in R11S specifically for spawning jobs
   I'd prefer an architecture where the lambda is actually just a "job runner". This would give you something along the lines of "Fluid Lambdas" where these lambdas can just react to operations coming off the Kafka Stream. Functionality like this is included, but poorly documented or tested in the [Foreman lambda](http://%20https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/tree/main/server/routerlicious/packages/routerlicious/src/foreman)

Critically, listening to just the Ops is not a very good way to know the current state of a Distributed Data Structure. The Distributed Data Structures manage the merging of new operations into the state. Therefore easiest way to get the current state of DDS is to load the DDS.

### How do I load just one DDS?

This is actually fairly straightforward, if not well documented. You'll need to provide a requestHandler that can fetch just the DDS from the container. Ultimately, the Container does have the ability to virtualize everything that isn't requested. You'll need to load the container, but just request the specific DDS.

In pseudocode...

```js
const container = loader.resolve("fluid://URIToContainer");
const dds = await container.request("/ddspaths/uuid");
dds.getIndexData();
```

Answer (score 1):

I originally left this as a comment to SamBroner's response but it got too long.

The `ContainerRuntime` raises an `"op"` event for every op, so you can listen to that to implement something similar to #1. This is missing in the docs currently so it's not obvious.

I think interpreting ops without loading the DDS code itself might be possible for DDSes with simpler merge logic, like SharedMap, but very challenging for SharedSequence, for example.

I guess it depends on the granularity of information you're trying to glean from the ops with general purpose code. Knowing *just* that a DDS was edited may be feasible, but knowing its resulting state... more difficult.